# PostgreSQL unaccent With SQLite And PHP / Doctrine / Symfony

Tags: php, postgresql, sqlite, symfony, doctrine-orm

My Symfony 2.8 / Doctrine 2 application uses a custom DQL function to support the PostgreSQL function [unaccent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/unaccent.html). I need it to compare strings by their base characters, e.g. "ä" should also match "a".

As my application grows, the phpunit tests take more than 20 minutes to complete, so I finally decided to run the tests in a SQLite Database and hopefully reduce the execution time significantly.

What is the best way to support the PostgreSQL `unaccent` function in SQLite? Should I apply the php [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.iconv.php) function to the relevant fields prior to passing them to the query?

Does anyone have solved a similar problem and can share a database indepedant solution (or at least one that's working either on the php side or on both databases, Postgresql and SQLite)? Are there any "best practices"? Any pitfalls to take in account?

Comment: You should look at why your tests are taking so long. Is any individual query the problem? Would storing the de-accented string in a separate column be worthwhile for performance reasons?

Comment: That's a good point, but the queries are mainly regarding larger "full-text" fields. So storing them de-accented in a separate column should not be an option. And the base question is more about HOW to de-accent the strings. For now, that's achieved via the postgresql `unaccent` function, but in SQLite this function is not available. So what is the best DB independant solution? PHP's iconv?

Comment: Most databases tackle this problem with [collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html), where collation describes the sort order of characters and their "equivalence". In some languages "ä" and "a" are two different letters, in some they're interchangeable. With the right collation settings you can get what you want without the `unaccent` mess.

Comment: Sounds promising. But I have to read it a bit more in detail. So, comparing strings such as "ä" and "a" in a query where a proper collation is set will treat them as eqal, right? And the collation used for the comparison can be set for each query only, so the default collations of the columns don't matter? That would truely be a clean solution to my problem.

Comment: You'll have to read up on it some more and see how it works in practice. This depends entirely on the type of data you're processing and how many collation style you need to juggle.